# Function to check whether the dates in the data set align

Tags: r, function, date, alignment

I want to generate a function that checks whether the dates of the three data sets in each row align.

```
x<-Gold_Mly$date 
y<-SMI_Mly$date 
z<-SP500_Mly$date

date.check <- function(x, y, z)
{ 
if (x=y=z)
{ 
print("dates align")
}
else { print("dates do not align")
}}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure what language this is, but usually you need == to compare two values. e.g. x == y

Comment: I tried it with "==". But I get the error: Unexpected '}' in "  }"